# Can I file_put_contents to send to an http web address?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to have an event trigger that once it does it sends the content to a text file from another web address that I should have access to. I've tried the code below but it will not allow me to do so, the error report reads,

> "failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable
>   connections in /data/custom/test-alarm-upload.php on line 36"

Is this even possible to do in php?

```
<?php

if (file_exists($myFile)) 
{
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $Gas_Seperator = fread($fh, 12); 
    fclose($fh);
    $Gas_Seperator = ereg_replace("[^0-9.-]", "", $Gas_Seperator);
    $Gas_Seperator = ($Gas_Seperator * 25) - 12.5;
}                           

$theday = date (j);
$themonth = date (F);
$theyear = date (Y);
$thetime = date (g);
$theAMPM = date (A);
$thest = date (S);

$entry ="\n" . $themonth . " " . $theday . "" . $thest . " " . $thetime . "" . $theAMPM . "," . $Gas_Seperator;

file_put_contents('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/data/custom/alarm.txt' , $entry, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: pretty sure the answer is no, file_put_contents cannot do that, but through stream context, file_get_contents actually can. but you shouldn't bother, curl is much better suited for these kind of things than file_get_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do so using HTTP protocole. You can do it using FTP.
Here is a sample of code to open and write file overt FTP.

```
$content = "Here is my content";
$fp = fopen("ftp://username:password@host/data/custom/alarm.txt","w");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
```

Host can be IP address or just domain name. Another way is that you can create on the second server a WebService that will do the Job. So when event triggers you just call the WebService that will do the Job.

Answer (score 2):

No. [The `http://` and `https://` wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) only support read operations:

> **Description**: Allows read-only access to files/resources via HTTP 1.0, using the HTTP GET method.

While the wrappers could conceivably implement write operations via the `PUT` method, most web applications do not implement that method, so it wouldn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

As per [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the **[fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)** have been **enabled**. See [**fopen()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.